# Should I sacrifice readability for speed using inline code vs function calls in C# NET4?

Tags: c#, .net, emulation, z80

I am writing a Z80 Emulator in C#, second time. First time was incredibly slow using a bunch of if statements and function calls, so I am rewriting using using switch/case instead. VS2019 C# .NET 4

For simple instruction execution there aren't many lines of code, but some instructions pretty much require tons of code and adding so much code inline makes the code difficult to read.

So I am wondering whether to use function calls for the flags, especially the ones that require a lot of code or take the line count hit for the sake of speed.

ex:

```
case 188:
    byteCount = 1;
    mnemonic = "CP H      ";
    dest = int.Parse(txtRegA.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    src = int.Parse(txtRegH.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    result = dest - src;
    // Zero Flag
    if (result == 0) { ZeroFlag.Text = "1"; } else { ZeroFlag.Text = "0"; }
    // Carry Flag
    if (dest < result) { CarryFlag.Text = "1"; } else { CarryFlag.Text = "0"; }
    SignFlag.Text = "1";
    //N Flag
    if (result > 127) { AddSubFlag.Text = "1"; } else { AddSubFlag.Text = "0"; }
    // Overflow
    //Subtract
    if ((src>127 & dest >127) | ( src< 127 & dest <127)) { POFlag.Text = "0"; } else { POFlag.Text = "1"; }
    // Add
    //if ((src > 127 & dest <= 127) | (src < 127 & dest >= 127)) { POFlag.Text = "0"; } else { POFlag.Text = "1"; }
    // Half Carry - Note: The Registers are already in HEX format
    dest = Convert.ToInt32(txtRegA.Text.Substring(4, 4));
    src = Convert.ToInt32(txtRegH.Text.Substring(4, 4));
    // Subtract
    if (dest < src) { HalfCarryFlag.Text = "1"; } else { HalfCarryFlag.Text = "0"; }
    // Add
    //result = dest + src;
    //if ((dest + src)>31) { HalfCarryFlag.Text = "1"; } else { HalfCarryFlag.Text = "1"; }
    run = true;
    break;
```

I am not at all sure about whether my half carry and overflow flags will work properly at all.

Not all instructions affect all flags so some in-line will be better. But, the multi-line flags...

Thoughts comments

Comment: Clean up the code so you can improve performance where it counts. All those substring operations generate new temporary strings that have to be allocated and garbage-collected. That's orders of magnitude slower than any assumed benefits from inlining. Besides, both the C# and the JIT compiler itself will inline code if possible

Comment: Benchmark with some production-like data before assuming you actually gain something.

Comment: Right now the code is hard to read. I suspect it's possible to replace multiple `if`s with pattern matching. Z80 registers were 8-bit, so instead of parsing their contents you could map them to their values. Or, instead of strings, they could be `Char`s. Chars can be cast to `int`s and support addition and subtraction

Comment: A basic way to organize the code better is to write a method for each instruction.  If you want it fast then you do have to get rid of the Parse() and Convert calls.  Keep the registers stored in `int` variables.  You only have to display them as text at the rate of the human eye.

Comment: A Z80 at 2.5MHz was at least 1000 times slower than a modern laptop. If the emulator feels slow, it's not the ifs and cases that caused delays. There are more serious issues. Trying to allocate 2.5M temporary strings per second is very slow and very wasteful. Never mind having to garbage-collect so many millions of objects

Comment: There are a few simple things you could do to this code to make it easier to read without affecting performance at all.

Comment: Is there a strong reason for you to be using .NET 4? I hope you realize there were absolutely _massive_ performance gains over the past handful of .NET releases. If you want maximum performance, I'd suggest using .NET 7 and upgrade to 8 as soon as you can.

Comment: I truly appreciate all your comments.

Not sure if or where to publish my projects where the entire mess can be critiqued.

As a fledgling programmer such critique, gently given, is greatly appreciated.

I may just a add a Projects and Programming page on my Web Site at houseofmyrrh.org

Answer (score 2):

The golden rule of optimization is to profile *first*. Sometimes formulated as [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil):

> There is no doubt that the grail of efficiency leads to abuse. Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Over time you tend to get a little bit better at guessing what will be slow or not. I would observe that it looks like your code is doing a few different things:

1. Logic operations, i.e. shifts etc
2. String operations
3. UI updates

Each of these things are order of magnitudes different with regards to performance. Something like updating the UI is many order of magnitudes slower than a simple method call.

My recommendations would be to

1. Start by doing some profiling, and/or benchmarking. That should give you some clues to what is slow, and familiarize yourself with the tools.
2. Focus on organization and readability before you attempt to do any optimization. Well organized code can usually be optimized one you know what parts are actually causing problems. Trying to optimize messy code tend to just break things all over.
3. Separate the actual emulation from things like UI. So that the actual emulation can run faster than the UI updates. You could use a one of the UI-timers to work as a clock for your emulation.
4. Try to reduce string handling as much as possible. If you are reading values from the UI you want to parse & validate values when they change, and only then. The rest of the code should use the the parsed values.

You *might* also consider running the emulation on a background thread, but doing so will require your program to be thread safe. So I would only consider this if you are familiar with thread safety, or are prepared to learn about it before you attempt it.